# Adding a string to an Array in IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, copy, nsmutablearray

I was wondering how to add a string to a mutable array without having to change the original array. So I'm thinking I have to make a copy of the array argument and then add the string to that.

```
    -(NSMutableArray *)arrayByAddingString:(NSString *)string toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
     {
       NSArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

       [newArray arrayByAddingObject:[string]];

return array;
}
```

I get the error Expected identifer, not sure what that means.

Comment: simple do like   `[newArray arrayByAddingObject: string];`

Comment: your `newArray` is `NSArray`. It should be `NSMutableArray` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u are creating the new array as just `NSArray` which is not mutable, and also the object u are trying to add is string why to use of `[string]`, u can do like below,

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)arrayByAddingString:(NSString *)string toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
  {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    [newArray addObject:string]; //no need of square brace, because string is an object 
    return newArray; //return the new array not the `array`
 }
```

Comment: it is not neccessary to reinitialize the array with arrayWithArray

Answer (score 2):

Use addObject method:

```
[array addObject:@"HEllo"];
```

Where array is a   `NSMutableArray`

In you example method, it will be like this:

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)arrayByAddingString:(NSString *)string toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
   return [array addObject:string];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do is

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)arrayByAddingString:(NSString *)string toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
   return [array addObject:string];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are extra `[]` in the code, change it to:

```
[newArray arrayByAddingObject:string];
```

Comment: arrayByAddingObject reinitialize the array and add the new item to that, while the question only wants to add the item to the current array and reinitializing this is not neccessary

Answer (score 0):

It should be like;

```
-(NSMutableArray *)arrayByAddingString:(NSString *)string toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
    {
           [array addObject:string];

            return array;
    }
```

Comment: it is not neccessary to reinitialize the array with arrayWithArray .

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

> In Swift

```
func arrayByAddingString(string: String, array: NSMutableArray) -> {
array.addObject(String)
return array
}
```

> In Objective C

```
-(NSMutableArray *)arrayByAddingString:(NSString *)string toArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{
[array addObject:string];    
return array;
}
```